# Coq modular arithmetic

Tags: coq, proof

How do static analyzers prove overflow using Coq?

Do they have their own definitions of integers and not use the given sets?
Or does coq have an inbuilt type for n-bit integers and operations on them?

Comment: Which particular static analyzers are you thinking of?  There is a library for n-bit integers in the [standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/index.html), but you don't have to use it.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean, but indeed the usual way is to have a type of integers `'I_n` of size n.